# Regex: Replace inline CSS with BB Code

Tags: css, regex, inline, bbcode

I have to replace all HTML markup in a text with BB Codes, and I am struggling with replacing the inline CSS styled elements.

HTML:

```
<span style="font-family: arial;">Arial</span>
<span style="font-size: 7px;">small text</span>
<span style="color: skyblue;">Blue Text</span>
<div align="center">centered text</div>
```

Should get replaced by the following:
BB Code:

```
[FONT=arial]Arial[/FONT]
[SIZE=7]small text[/SIZE]
[COLOR=skyblue]Blue Text[/COLOR]
[CENTER]centered text[/CENTER]
```

whereas the font families, color codes, and size values can differ.

Non working starting point:

```
$text = preg_replace('#<span style="color: (.*?);">(.*?)</span>#siU', '[color=$1]$2[/color]', $text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$text = preg_replace('/<span style="color: (.*?);">(.*?)<\/span>/siU', '[color=$1]$2[/color]', $text);
```

I just replaced the `#` with `/` and it's working for me.
As for the other replacements:

```
/<span style="font-size: (.*?)px;">(.*?)<\/span>/
[size=$1]$2[/size]

/<span style="font-family: (.*?);">(.*?)<\/span>/
[font=$1]$2[/font]

/<div align="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/div>/
[$1]$2[/$1]
```

**UPDATE**
Fiddled it: [phpfiddle.org/main/code/zqu-bgs](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zqu-bgs)
(end escaped the `/` of the closing tags)

Comment: I tried the first one, but the output I got was the following: 
 
`[color=skyblue;">sky blue`

Comment: @FletcherDuran Works like a charme for me, see the fiddle... only thing was I forgot to escape the `/` of the closing tags, corrected this.

Comment: My apologies, you were right; the error was at my end. Seems some other cleansing messed it up; putting your Regex first before all the other things it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str1 = '<span style="font-family: arial;">Arial</span>'; 
$str2 = '<span style="font-size: 7px;">small text</span>';
$str3 = '<span style="color: skyblue;">Blue Text</span>';

$reg_exp=  '/<span\s*style=\"\s*(.*?):\s*(.*?)\s*;\s*\">\s*(.*?)\s*<\/span>/';
$reg_exp_rep = '[$1=$2]$3[/$1]';


$text=preg_replace($reg_exp,$reg_exp_rep, $str1);
echo htmlspecialchars($str1).' <=> '.$text.'<br />';
$text=preg_replace($reg_exp,$reg_exp_rep, $str2);
echo htmlspecialchars($str2).' <=> '.$text.'<br />';
$text=preg_replace($reg_exp,$reg_exp_rep, $str3);
echo htmlspecialchars($str3).' <=> '.$text.'<br />';
```

Result:

```
<span style="font-family: arial;">Arial</span> <=> [font-family=arial]Arial[/font-family]
<span style="font-size: 7px;">small text</span> <=> [font-size=7px]small text[/font-size]
<span style="color: skyblue;">Blue Text</span> <=> [color=skyblue]Blue Text[/color]
```

This is for span tags in general. If you want more different tag recognition or something more specific, you have to define it.

--

EDIT: Something more specific, and that you asked for.

```
unset($str1,$str2,$str3,$str4,$str5,$str6,$str7,$reg_exp);

$str1 = '
    <span style="font-family: arial;">Arial</span> 
    <span style="font-size: 7px;">small text</span>
    <span style="color: skyblue;">Blue Text</span>
    <div align="center">centered text</div>';

$reg_exp[0] =  '/<span\s*style=\"\s*(.*?):\s*(.*?)\s*;\s*\">\s*(.*?)\s*<\/span>/';
$reg_exp_rep[0] = '[$1=$2]$3[/$1]';
$reg_exp[1] =  '/\[font-family(.*?)\/font-family\]/';
$reg_exp_rep[1] = '[FONT$1/FONT]';
$reg_exp[2]=  '/\[font-size(.*?)\/font-size\]/';
$reg_exp_rep[2] = '[SIZE$1/SIZE]';
$reg_exp[3] =  '/\[color(.*?)\/color\]/';
$reg_exp_rep[3] = '[COLOR$1/COLOR]';
$reg_exp[4] =  '/<div\s*align=\"\s*center\s*"\s*\>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/div>/';
$reg_exp_rep[4]= '[CENTER]$1[/CENTER]';

$text=$str1;
foreach ($reg_exp as $ii => $exp) {
    $text=preg_replace($exp,$reg_exp_rep[$ii], $text);
}
    echo htmlspecialchars($str1).' <=> '.$text.'<br />';
```

Result:

```
<span style="font-family: arial;">Arial</span> <span style="font-size: 7px;">small text</span> <span style="color: skyblue;">Blue Text</span> <div align="center">centered text</div> <=> 
[FONT=arial]Arial[/FONT] [SIZE=7px]small text[/SIZE] [COLOR=skyblue]Blue Text[/COLOR] [CENTER]centered text[/CENTER]
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working but it doesn't handle nested tags correctly. For example, `<span style="font-family: comic sans ms;"><span style="font-size: 7px;"><span style="color: orangered;">comic+winzig+orange-red</span></span></span>` would incorrectly is replaced by `[FONT=comic sans ms]comic+winzig+orange-red[/FONT]` only.